# Stan logistic regression with binary independent variables

Tags: stan

I am developing my very first Stan (MCMC) model and naturally got hit by a problem. This is probably a very basic issue, but I did not find an answer in Stan documentation so asking your help now.
My model is logistic regression. The data-block of my model is the following, and I get compiler error "No matches for: real * int[ ]"

```
m1 <- 'data {                          
    int<lower=0> N;                       // number of observations
    int<lower=0,upper=1> Result[N];       // binary dependent variable
    vector[N] RealValVar;                 // real valued independent variable 
    int<lower=0,upper=1> BinaryValVar[N]; // binary valued independent variable 
}
```

When I changed the last variable to vector Stan compiler is happy.

```
 ....
 vector[N] RealValVar;   // real valued independent variable 
 vector[N] BinaryValVar; // binary valued independent variable 
 ....
```

My question is, what is the correct Stan way to include binary independent variables into the model?

Comment: As per the advice of a Stan developer, you're best to ask questions on the [discourse](https://discourse.mc-stan.org) rather than here as few Stan developers check Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the two variables are inconsistent types Since these are variables in your logistic regression, there is no reason they can't be treated as floats, and so I would encourage you to do so.

Here is a simplified copy of your Stan model

```
data{
  int N;
  real xc[N];
  int xb[N];
  int y[N]; //Binary outcome
}
parameters{
  real b0;
  real b1;
  real b2;
}
model{
  b0~normal(0,1);
  b1~normal(0,1);
  b2~normal(0,1);
  y~bernoulli_logit(b0 + b1*xc + b2*xb);
}
```

This model errors out with the following message

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
No matches for: 

  real * real[ ]

Available argument signatures for operator*:

  real * real
  vector * real
  row_vector * real
  matrix * real
  row_vector * vector
  vector * row_vector
  matrix * vector
  row_vector * matrix
  matrix * matrix
  real * vector
  real * row_vector
  real * matrix

No matches for: 

  real + ill-formed

Available argument signatures for operator+:

  int + int
  real + real
  vector + vector
  row_vector + row_vector
  matrix + matrix
  vector + real
  row_vector + real
  matrix + real
  real + vector
  real + row_vector
  real + matrix
  +int
  +real
  +vector
  +row_vector
  +matrix

No matches for: 

  real * int[ ]

Available argument signatures for operator*:

  real * real
  vector * real
  row_vector * real
  matrix * real
  row_vector * vector
  vector * row_vector
  matrix * vector
  row_vector * matrix
  matrix * matrix
  real * vector
  real * row_vector
  real * matrix

No matches for: 

  ill-formed + ill-formed

Available argument signatures for operator+:

  int + int
  real + real
  vector + vector
  row_vector + row_vector
  matrix + matrix
  vector + real
  row_vector + real
  matrix + real
  real + vector
  real + row_vector
  real + matrix
  +int
  +real
  +vector
  +row_vector
  +matrix

Expression is ill formed.
 error in 'model368e1c9443af_stan_368e727bc831' at line 17, column 38
  -------------------------------------------------
    15:   b1~normal(0,1);
    16:   b2~normal(0,1);
    17:   y~bernoulli_logit(b0 + b1*xc + b2*xb);
                                             ^
    18: }
  -------------------------------------------------

Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'stan-368e727bc831' due to the above error.
```

I'm confident that this is because the continuous and integer variables are treated as `real`/`int` and not as vectors.  Changing the `data` block to

```
data{
  int N;
  //changes here
  vector[N] xc;
  vector[N] xb;
  //Rest the same
  int y[N];
}
```

compiles the model.